# ScrollView with loop inside of it Not Scrolling React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm running a loop inside a ScrollView and for no apparent reason it doesn't scroll. I've read other posts where they set flex:1 or flexGrow:1 which I tried but it still doesn't work.

I'm using expo to run the app on my android device.

fooditems.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Divider, Image } from "react-native-elements";

const foods = [
  {
    title: "chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,  recusandae error amet cum doloremque mollitia hic, porro autem qui libero fugit atque.",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 10.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
];
export default function MenuItems() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {foods.map((food, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
            <FoodInfo food={food} />
            <FoodImage food={food} />
          </View>
          <Divider width={0.5} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuItemStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 20,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
});
```

I'm not too sure why this is happening but on ios there don't seem to be such a problem.

**EDIT: Same code with FlatList but it still won't scroll**.

```
export default function MenuItems() {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
        <FoodInfo food={item} />
        <FoodImage food={item} />
      </View>
      <Divider
        width={0.5}
        orientation="vertical"
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={foods}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuItemStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 20,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
});
const FoodInfo = (props) => (
  <View style={{ width: 240, justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{props.food.title}</Text>
    <Text>{props.food.description}</Text>
    <Text>{props.food.price}</Text>
  </View>
);

const FoodImage = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: props.food.image }}
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 9 }}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Try using a Flatlist which is much more efficient and better compared to what you have done. <View><FlatList/></View>

Answer (score 1):

import FoodInfo and FoodImage

I would suggest you to use FlatList instead of scroll view, bcz a large number of data(JSON) is smoothly handled only by flatlist, In future if u r using Any api request for data then its better to go with flatlist

optionally u can reder the view horizontally visit https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

```
example
import React from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

const Foods = [
  {
    title: "chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,  recusandae error amet cum doloremque mollitia hic, porro autem qui libero fugit atque.",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 10.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.container}>    
      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.description}</Text>
      <Text>{item.image}</Text>
      <Text>{item.price}</Text>
     <View style={{width: "100%", backgroundColor: 'white', height:   
      3,}}/>
      </View>
  );

  return (
   <View >
      <FlatList
        data={Foods}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
   </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'gray'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm following a tutorial and this is pretty confusing right now. It should be possible to use ScrollView

Comment: Yeah you need to import these two components in your app folder.
 <FoodInfo food={food} />
 <FoodImage food={food} />

Comment: that's "unnecessary" code that's why I didn't add it at first but let me add it so it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

If your items are similar in structure always recommend using **FlatList**.
It will optimize memory usage.
[Flatlist documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

But if you still want to use **ScrollView** use this code. This is working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Divider, Image } from "react-native-elements";

const foods = [
  {
    title: "chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,  recusandae error amet cum doloremque mollitia hic, porro autem qui libero fugit atque.",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 10.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
  {
    title: "barbecued chicken",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque quis quam architecto. ",
    image:
      "some image link",
    price: "$ 14.99",
  },
];

const MenuItems = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {foods.map((food, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{food.description}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{food.price}</Text>
          </View>
          <Divider width={0.5} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuItemStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 20,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
});

export default MenuItems;
```